# add array value to key javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, key, addition

i'm getting the data from a form when it is submitted like this

```
        values = {};

        $("#myForm").submit(function(){
            $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
                if(field.name != 'r'){
                    values[field.name] = field.value;

                }
            }); 

            return false;
        });
```

The problem is that i want to do that multiple times and store all the data in the var values using field.name as a keys and the values as an array
to compare it in php i would do values[field.name][] = field.value;
is there any similar syntax in js ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you can add multiple values using the `Array.push` method. But first, you must define `values[field.name]` as array, like this:

```
values[field.name] = [];
values[field.name].push(somevalue);
```

Comment: Thank you i tried push before but i didn't know i had to define the array first